What entire functions $g$ satisfy the strict inequality $ |g(z)| > |\sin(z)|^{2022}?$
I'm trying to find every entire function $g$ such that $|g(z)|  > |\sin(z)|^{2022}$, and it has struck me that the strict inequality impies that $g$ doesn't vanish anywhere. That in it's turn probably implies that the function $\frac {(\sin(z))^{2022}} {g(z)}$ is entire provided that $g$ is. And the magnitude of the quotient function seems to be strictly less than 1 everywhere. In particular,  the quotient function is bounded, hence constant by Liouville's theorem.
So $g$ probably has to be of the form $a\times (\sin(z))^{2022}$, where a is a constant.
Now the strict inequality seems to be satisfied if and only if the magnitude of $a$ is strictly greater than 1. Am I right or wrong?

but since $\sin(z)$ vanishes, the strict inequality cannot be satisfied so no such $g$ exists.

Yea that's right. Note that $g(z)=a (\sin z)^{2022}$ for some constant $a$ by your argument. However this is a contracting the assumption for $z = \pi$.

Ok, so maybe I overlooked something in the last step of my argument?
